# Spotify blocked by firewall - use proxy on custom app to bypass firewall

Tags: javascript, express, spotify, http-proxy

So at my new workplace, I found out that spotify.com and all the other domains (api.spotify.com or accounts.spotify.com) are blocked by the firewall. My idea to bypass this was to create an application to use instead of the official Spotify App.

So I have started here https://github.com/spotify/spotify-web-playback-sdk-example, but I didn't do any modifications yet.

The question that I have is this one: can I use Express (or really any other language, doesn't need to be Javascript, I can do it in Laravel as well) to kind of proxy all the requests coming from Spotify to not be from Spotify itself but from my application? So what I mean is even there are requests made to Spotify, only the app does them while the client is getting responses only from the app (including the login, the requests made by the WebPlayer SDK or Spotify API) to not get blocked by the firewall.

Comment: Even if it doesn't work or I choose to not use it I would still like the knowledge on how to do it.

Comment: The only reason I specified the workplace firewall is to provide a reason on why would I want to do this.....